# How to set file or url "open with" programmatically?

Tags: android, android-file

[image]

When the file or url open, Android ask to user how to open with. My application need to set this option. I cannot completed to finish making application if no solution. Please tell me how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you share a file with `Intent` you can first create your `Intent openWith` object (but not run it yet). Then list all available activities for it like this:

```
PackageManager pm = (Activity)this.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(openWith, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
    ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
    String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
    String label = (String) ri.loadLabel(pm);
    String activity = ri.activityInfo.name;
    // choose needed packageName and activity here
}
```

Then add selected packageName and activity pair to the intent for "open with" action:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, activity));
```

and run it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement ability open files/urls at your app, right?
Here is doc https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html
So your 'viewer' activity must have intent filter like this

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="http|https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: No. Using google drive.